# Why do I get such low fps in games on linux mint?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, gaming

Like the title says, my frame-rate for easy-to-run games like minecraft and enter the gungeon is in the single digits, which it should not be. When I boot into Windows I can get more than 30 fps for each game, but on linux mint i get about 5 fps average. I've tried updating kernel and drivers, I don't know what else to do? Any suggestions appreciated.

Part of output from lscpi:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

Output from `glxinfo | grep 'OpenGl.*string'`:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile 
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.2 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.2.8
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.20
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 19.2.8
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 19.2.8
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
```

Comment: Please edit your question to tell us what graphics card you're using (from `lspci`) and what drivers you're using (from `glxinfo | grep 'OpenGL.*string'`).

Comment: Any ideas? Or is this just strange?